# How to save (persist, serialize) beans to disk and restore (deserialize) them next run in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, persistence

I would like my application to remember it's state on disk. So, some of my beans are stateful and I wish to save and load their states.

Suppose I am creating beans with method like

```
@Bean
    MyBean myBean() {
        MyBean ans;
        if( /* bean is already written to disk */ ) {
            ans = readMyBean();
        }
        else {
            ans = new MyBean();
            ans.property1 = defaultValue1;
            // ...
        }
        return ans;

    }
```

Is this correct approach? Or I need to consider some existing Spring API?

Where to call save methods?

**UPDATE**

Currently I do the following way

I am using `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` to create my application. I feed it with java config classes, having appropriate creators for beans.

Serialization is called in business logic, while deserialization is made in creation code:

```
public class MyConfig {

    protected String getConfigName() {
        String name = getClass().getSimpleName();
        name = name.split("\\$\\$")[0];
        return name;
    }

    @Bean
    MyDirectoryBean myDirectoryBean() {
        MyDirectoryBean ans = new MyDirectoryBean (new File("data/" + getConfigName()));
        return ans;
    }

    @Bean(name="mybean")
    MyBean myBean() {

        MyBean ans = (MyBean) myDirectoryBean().deserialize("mybean");
        if( ans == null ) {
            ans =new MyBean();
            ans.setMyParameter1(100); // etc
        }
        return ans;

    }
}
```

My class `MyDirectoryBean` is able to serialize and deserialize beans.

Unfortunately, this way requires me to code bean name two times: in bean creator annotation and in the line where deserialization occurs.

I am imagining some interface to intercept the creation process. May be some `BeanPreProcessor` class? By there is no such class. May be I could override `getBean()` method in my custom context, so that it first try to deserialize bean?

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: If you're `MessageService` is a stateless object, then It's  easier to create a new object than to reconstruct it from a stream specially when that object doesn't have any state but only behavior. What do you think is the advantage you get in your case by persisting objects to disk ?

Comment: It requires work and can cause many problems when doing that. So i don't see any reasons, why you would want to do that.

Comment: Millions of programs are storing their state to the disk. I am one of the million. Stateless programs do exist but probably not written with such things as Spring.

Comment: @Arkantos MessageService is stateful. Why would I wish to save it otherwise?

Comment: I'm still not convinced with the idea of persisting beans. Is your `MessageService` a prototype or singleton ?? From your bean definition it looks like its a prototype. Like dunni said it's complicated, somewhere in your code you have to serialize your bean, write it to some file and in your `mockMessageService()`, you have to de-serialize the object from that file and you should be careful while doing as you have to do it only once, so you might have some variable within `Configuration` class indicating that. It's easy to say than to implement and this one definitely needs serious work :)

Comment: It is a difference if you save any data in a database and read that if you need it, or if you store serialized objects.

Comment: I am astonished that Spring is in opposite to persisted applications. Nowadays all applications are persistent. Text processors remember previously opened files, Web browsers remember last visited page. Media players remember played clips and positions you stop. Are you seriously mean that Spring is not intended to write all types of these applications? What is it for then? To write hello world app?

Comment: @Arkantos why should I check if deserializing made once? Isn't container controller caches instances?

Comment: @dunni I don't care which way I persist my data. It can be database, disk file or gauge field. The question is how Spring handle it.

Comment: If you directly write your de-serialization code in `mockMessageService()`, then it will deserialize that object from file every time someone asks for your bean. We don't want to that operation again and again because the state in that file is always same, that's why we need to do that only once

Comment: Spring is not against persistence, it has a decent persistence API but we don't usually use persist beans because they can be re-created easily with a container restart. we usually persist states related to some user transaction or some process's progress. In your examples of text processor and webapps, remembering states makes it easier for the user. What is the advantage you see by persisting beans ?

Comment: Everything is beans, isn't it? Persisting something mean persist beans. Isn't it?

Comment: For example, writing browser, I will have a bean "History" and it will persist.

Comment: Container will cache Singleton instances as they don't need to be created again and again but if it's a prototype bean, your bean method will be invoked every time someone asks the container for a bean. My guess is that your bean should be Singleton because the state stored in file is always same, but your original bean definition returns a new instance every time, so two contradicting arguments :-)

Comment: @Arkantos so you mean container doesn't contain beans actually? Each time someone asking for bean "MyBean" new instance is created?

Comment: Isn't `@Bean` annotation makes singleton bean by default?

Comment: @Arkantos why did you think my bean is prototype????

Comment: Yes you're correct, my mistake :) As you're using just `@Bean` without any `@Scope` annotation, that will be defined as a Singleton bean and that method will be invoked only once, no matter how many times you times you ask the spring container for that bean, so it doesn't matter if its returning a new instance without any checks.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is Serialization, you can find many example about how to serialize object and de-serialize it for example:

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=45
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

and you can make de-serialization code inside your @Bean method.

but I have 2 debates both based on extracting data in java bean with data and getter/setters and make your bean configurable based on this java bean

1. persist this java bean it on DB using jpa and you can use something like H2 database with jdbc:h2:~/test or jdbc:h2:file:/data/sample
2. Using Spring resources and put your data in properties files to read it then with @Value

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar with Spring Integration beans
The basic idea is to have one main spring context and at sometime you can load a child context.

Example child context;

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration" xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
   <context:property-placeholder/>
   <int:channel id="ch.file.in"/>
   <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter directory="${file.dir}" channel="ch.file.in">
      <int:poller fixed-rate="${file.pollInterval}"/>
   </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
   <bean id="fileBatchRunner" class="com.nevexis.dcard.integration.serviceactivator.FileBatchRunner">
      <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher"/>
      <property name="job" ref="fileImportJob"/>
   </bean>
   <int:service-activator input-channel="ch.file.in" ref="fileBatchRunner" method="transform"/>
</beans>
```

Then you can load it as a child to the root context:

```
public class ContextRegisterImpl implements ContextRegister, ApplicationContextAware{
    private ApplicationContext parentCtx;
    private Map<String, ConfigurableApplicationContext> contexts;
    public ContextRegisterImpl() {
        contexts = new HashMap<String, ConfigurableApplicationContext>();
    }
    public void loadContext(String name, String path, Properties props) throws ContextAlreadyLoadedException {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = 
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { path }, false, parentCtx);
        setEnvironment(ctx, props);
        ctx.refresh();
        contexts.put(name, ctx);
    }
    public void shutdownContext(String name) throws ContextNotOpenException {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = contexts.get(name);
        if(context != null){
            context.close();
            contexts.remove(name);
        }
    }
    private void setEnvironment(ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx, Properties props) {
        StandardEnvironment env = new StandardEnvironment();
        PropertiesPropertySource pps = new PropertiesPropertySource("childCtxProps", props);
        env.getPropertySources().addLast(pps);
        ctx.setEnvironment(env);
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

The thing that is loaded form the disk/database are the properties. You have to supply a prop for every placeholder(`${...}`). Then `setEnvironment` will put them in the context's environment and when you load it, the `property-placeholder` will replace the placeholders with the actual values.

Notice that child context can see and use beans from the parent, but the parent cant see beans from it's children.
This example is with Spring integration, but its the same with normal beans.

I got the idea from: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp

Another option is to load bean definitions directly in the root context:

```
if(beanExists(beanName, rootCtx)){ throw new BeanExitstException(beanName+" already exists!"); }
        AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = rootCtx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) factory;
        registry.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, beanDef);
```

See the BeanDefinition interface: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it by implementing [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). Here an examplary code: When running the first time, the Object is saved. The second time, it is loaded.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class SerializeTest implements Serializable{
    private static SerializeTest p;
    private static String fileName;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        fileName = "test.data";
        File f = new File(fileName);


        if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
            FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            ObjectInputStream oIn = new ObjectInputStream (fIn);
            Object object = oIn.readObject();

            if(object instanceof SerializeTest) {
                p = (SerializeTest) object;
                System.out.println("Successfully loaded!");
            }
            else
                System.err.println("Invalid object in " + fileName);

            fIn.close();
            oIn.close();
        }
        else {
            p = new SerializeTest();
            System.out.println("Successfully created!");
        }

        save(p);
    }

    public static void save(SerializeTest p) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        ObjectOutputStream oOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fOut);
        oOut.writeObject(p);

        fOut.close();
        oOut.close();
    }
}
```